# Hide / Show div on select - option change not working

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide, show

I am trying to display div on change of select option change.

I have get data of each selected option on change but I want to display that name div on change of select item.

when I click on option that will show that div and when i ll change select item then it ll change div and above display div will invisible.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/nCRh6/1/)

code :

```
$( "select" )
      .change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $( this ).text() + " ";
        });
          alert(str);
        $( ".mobile" ).show();
      })
      .change();
```

what I will have to use on  `$( ".mobile" ).show();` line ?
I have tried  `$( .str ).show();` but not working.
i want to change div on select change.

I have displayed alert box that will show text of option selected.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/nCRh6/8/)

**Markup:**

```
<select name="sweets">
    <option value="1">laptop</option>
    <option value="2">mobile</option>
    <option value="3">shoes</option>
    <option value="4">watch</option>
    <option value="5">tablet</option>
    <option value="6">shirt</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="device laptop" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">laptop</div>
<div class="device mobile" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">mobile</div>
<div class="device shoes" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1;">shoes</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$("select")
    .change(function () {
    var str = $("select option:selected").text();
    $(".device").hide();
    $("." + str).show();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

change this `$( ".mobile" ).show();` to  this = > `$("."+str).show();`

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/5/)

since you have hard-coded your jQ to `.mobile`, it is not changing!! :)

So final jQ is

```
$("select")
    .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    alert(str);
    $("."+str).show(); /* changed here*/
})
    .change();
```

**EDIT**

for that you can use

`$( "div:visible" ).hide();`

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/12/)

Comment: Yes sir right but when I change the item above div should be done invisible.

Comment: and when I run page, no div should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like this -

```
$("select").change(function () {
       $('div').hide();
       $('.'+$('option:selected',this).text()).show();
}).change();
```

Demo `----->`  http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/7/

Comment: when I run page, no div should be visible, what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "select" )
          .change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
              str += $( this ).text() + " ";
            });
              alert(str);
              $('div').hide()
              $("."+str).show();
          })
          .change();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
$( ".mobile" ).show();
```

to this:

```
$("."+str).show().siblings('div').hide();
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCRh6/9/)

Comment: when I run page, no div should be visible, what to do ?

Comment: You can omit the traling `.change()` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

just put:

```
$( "div:visible" ).hide();

$( "."+str ).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('div').hide();
$( "." + str).show();
```

Fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/nCRh6/11/)